# ¿Cómo re-direccionar URLs con subdirectorios dinámicos?

Tags: php, php5, url, redirección

Tengo el siguiente código, que me funciona perfectamente cuando tengo los archivos en un mismo nivel de directorio.
Con el transcurso del tiempo he seguido metiendo cosas a la página web y fue necesario crear varios niveles de subdirectorio, lo cual hace que este código ya no funcione.

No uso ningún plugin, ¿hay alguna forma de lograr re-direccionar mis URLs sin importar los niveles de directorio en dónde se encuentren mis archivos?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-principal">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="img/home/logo.png" alt="CDCGroup"></a> 
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu-principal">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
                <li class="hidden"><a href="#page-top"></a></li>
                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="nosotros.php">Nosotros</a></li>
                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="index.php#soluciones">Soluciones</a></li>
                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="index.php#capacitacion">Capacitación</a></li>
                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="marcas.php">Marcas</a></li>
                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="index.php#sucursales">Sucursales</a></li>
                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="index.php#contact">Contacto</a></li>
                <li><a class="page-scroll" href="promociones.php">Promociones</a></li>
                <li class="redes-sociales">
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container -->  
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno ya que esta programando en PHP para crear el HTML según veo en la etiqueta de usaste `php`y `php5`, la recomendación es que crees un sistema de rutas.

Para esto es un `array` guardas las rutas con una clave para identificarlas , y con una función retornas la URL.

```php
 //rutas.php
 <?php
   $ruta = [
     "index"=> "index.php",
     "soluciones" => "index.php#soluciones",
     "marcas" => "marcas/index.php",
     "lenovo" => "marcas/lenovo.php"
   ];

   function getRuta($pagina = "index"){
       return in_array($pagina, $ruta) ? $ruta[$pagina]  : "404.php"
   }
```

Ahora este archivo los puede incluir en cualquier pagina para generar tus urls.

```php
//index.php
<?php
include "rutas.php";
?>
<a href="<?=getRuta("index")?>">HOME</a>
```